# pandas "where" function does not appear to short-circuit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm probably misunderstanding how this works. 
I was surprised that, given this dataframe:

```
A   B      C            D
0   9.0    Nonnumeric   9.0
2   9.0    Num0a        9.0
```

This DOES appear to short circuit (--GOOD!):

```
dfzero["B"] = pd.DataFrame.where(
                  cond = dfzero["A"] != 0,
                  self = 1/dfzero["A"],
                  other = 0)
```

But this does NOT (--BAD!):
(gives a divide by zero error, as there is no short-circuit):

```
df["D"] = pd.DataFrame.where(
              cond = df["C"].str.len() == 5,
              self = df["C"].str[-2:].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16)),
              other = 0)
```

The error is:

```
self = (df["C"].str[-2:].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'ic'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even the first method does NOT short circuit. Both of the operands must first be evaluated before the result is computed. Meaning, this is computed,

```
i = dfzero["A"] != 0
i

0    False
1     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

And so is this:

```
j = 1 / dfzero['A']
j

0         inf
1    0.500000
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

The expression is effectively:

```
pd.DataFrame.where(i, j, 0)
```

It's the same for the second. The behaviour is consistent.

Were you expecting a `ZeroDivisionError`? You won't get that with numpy or pandas, because these libraries assume you know what you're doing when you compute such quantities.

---

Your option here is to precompute the mask, and then compute the result for those rows only.

```
m = df["C"].str.len() == 5
df['D'] = df.loc[m, 'C'].str[-2:].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))

df

   A    B           C     D
0  0  9.0  Nonnumeric   NaN
1  2  9.0       Num0a  10.0
```

If you want to fill in the NaNs, use `df.loc[~m, 'D'] = fill_value`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, and never mind on the below warning: I got rid of it by copying to a new dataframe with a different name.  

That works, but I get the dreaded SettingWithCopyWarning (even though I am using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer]):
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead